# Microsoft Graph API Mail: updating whole conversations? (mark as read or delete)

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am developing using the Microsoft Mail Graph API I'd like to provide conversation actions.

For example, if a conversation has several unread messages, marking as read the last one doesn't mark the whole conversation as read (like I'd want).

I didn't see any conversation-level API to mark as read / mark as unread or delete whole conversations.

What would be the best way to achieve conversation updates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there are not APIs specific to email conversations. In order to process a batch of emails within a conversation, you'll need to update each message individually.

You can determine which messages belong in the conversation using the `conversationId`. Keep in mind however that a "conversation" is a somewhat loosely defined entity. Exchange generally gets good results but it isn't foolproof by a long shot (for example, a conversation with 10 participants, forward it to an 11th and you often end up with two threads in a single "conversation").

I would suggest using [JSON batching](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching) for something like this. Batching allows you to bundle multiple Graph commands into a single call. Using batching you could update up to 20 messages at a time.

Comment: I think I don't care if a single conversation is 2 threads. As long as they're shown as a single conversation in Outlook, clicking the "Delete" button in the Web App should delete both threads.

I'll retrieve all those messages and batch delete them :)